# jsonexception:Value Failed of type Java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I made a login system with php, before, for an android application, it worked, but now I modified a little the database, instead of fullname i changed into firstname and lastname, I added username, country,points and parentemail. I also modified the php code for the new structure of my table, and when I run it from my app, it gives me that error JSONException: Value of type java.lang:String cannot be converted to JSONObject, I watch de debug console but I couldnt find the issue. Can you please help me a little, I'm doing this for a school project.

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php';


$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);


if(isset($input['email']) && isset($input['password'])){
    $email = $input['email'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $query    = "SELECT username,password, firstname,lastname,country,parentEmail,points FROM users WHERE email = ?";

    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username,$passwordHashDB,$firstname, $lastname,$country,$parentEmail,$points);
        if($stmt->fetch()){

            if(password_verify($password,$passwordHashDB)){
                $response["status"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Login successful";
                $response["first_name"] = $firstname;
            }
            else{
                $response["status"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Invalid Email and password combination";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid Email and password combination";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

this is the php login from my website

```
private void login() {
        displayLoader();
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {

            request.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, login_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {


                            if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                                session.loginUser(email, response.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME));
                                loadDashboard();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace for "JSONException: Value of type java.lang:String cannot be converted to JSONObject" on Android?

Answer (score 0):

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            VolleyLog.wtf(response);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             try {
                     if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                            session.loginUser(email, response.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME));
                            loadDashboard();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        }
    }, errorListener) {
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return Priority.LOW;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);


            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

It is always better to make the StringRequests as in string and then pass them to jsonobject. Regards!

Comment: I got some errors at getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0, at getString, errorListener

Comment: Checked in the log if the request appears?

Comment: I mean, it doesnt run, doesnt recognize those